# Discord.js Client issue

Tags: node.js, express, routes, discord.js, router

Today I tried to work with express router and discord.js, but there is an error: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined. I don't know where is the problem. Maybe I set the wrong path. Thank you for your help.

```js
//app.js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new discord.Client()


router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', {
        title: 'Register'
    })
})


router.get('/Dashboard', (req, res) => {
    var chans = []
    client.guilds.cache.first().channels.cache
        .filter(c => c.type == 'text')
        .forEach(c => {
            chans.push({ id: c.id, name: c.name })
        })

    res.render('dashboard', {
        title: "Dashboard",
        chans,
    })
})
router.post('/sendMessage', (req, res) => {
    var channelid = req.body.channelid
    var text = req.body.text

    if (!channelid || !text)
        return res.sendStatus(400);

    var chan = client.guilds.cache.first().channels.cache.get(channelid)

    if (chan) {
        chan.send(text)
        res.sendStatus(200)
    }
    else
        res.sendStatus(406)
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var chan = client.guilds.cache.first().channels.cache.get(channelid)
```

with this:

```
var chan = client.guilds.cache.first().channels.cache.fetch(channelid)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Discord client and access its channels you must first login with your token

```js
await client.login(token_here)
```

or

```js
client.login(token_here).then(() => {...})
```

and Tomedic is correct you are using a mix of v11 and v12 syntax, if you read back on the v12 discord.js docs you will find that you can directly get your channel by doing

```js
let channel = await client.channels.fetch(channel_id)
```

or

```js
client.channels.fetch(channel_id).then((channel) => {...})
```